# A whisper is my death. Who am I?

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> I'm the delight of old and young,
> although I speak without a tongue.
>
> I'll crash and roar, and even rattle;
> I'll join in all the din of battle.
>
> Yet I hate a silent breath,
> and a whisper is my death.

Who am I?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As an idea, you could be

> Music

I'm the delight of old and young,

> Music is enjoyed by the old and young

although I speak without a tongue.

> Music does not have to be sung. It can be played on instruments.

I'll crash and roar, and even rattle;

> Music can be loud. Some percussion instruments can rattle. (And crash could be cymbals)

I'll join in all the din of battle.

> Songs can be sung before battle to rouse the troops. (And during battle — battle chant, maybe)

Yet I hate a silent breath,

> Music is of sound.

and a whisper is my death.

> When you are whispering, you have no musical pitch. Therefore you could argue that when you stop singing, and start to whisper, the music stops.

Comment: One must not forget for "Yet I hate a silent breath", that silences are as important as notes so it might not work because of that :(

Comment: Yeah - I thought that too. But perhaps someone could improve on my idea.

Answer (score 4):

You're:

> An explosion!

I'm the delight of old and young,

> Everybody loves watching fireworks and gun fights.

although I speak without a tongue.

> No tongue but a loud bang!

I'll crash and roar, and even rattle;

> Rockets roar into the air and then can crash into the ground and explode, and machine guns rattle.

I'll join in all the din of battle.

> There are explosions in battle from guns, cannons, bombs and missiles.

Yet I hate a silent breath,

> When a fuse wire goes silent just before exploding a firework or bomb or when firing a cannon.  It's that tense moment just before an explosion...

and a whisper is my death.

> .. or no bang at all but a whispered "Shhisstpth".  Which mean it's a dud firework or bomb.  And there's no bang, the explosion is killed.

Comment: A dude firework... for dudes....

Comment: @Will Choo dude...

Answer (score 1):

I guess that you are

> A car

I'm the delight of old and young

> people of all ages can be auto enthusiasts

although I speak without a tongue

> cars can have voiced navigation systems

I'll crash and roar, and even rattle;

> cars crash, their engines roar, things will rattle

I'll join in all the din of battle.

> Humvee

Yet I hate a silent breath,

> silent cars are off.

and a whisper is my death.

> car dies when it can't run and often makes that airy, coughing sound

Answer (score 1):

I would go with

> an onomatopoeia (but I don't know which one)

I'm the delight of old and young,
although I speak without a tongue.

> An onomatopoeia is used by anyone, old or young, but does not represent any formal language

I'll crash and roar, and even rattle;
I'll join in all the din of battle.

> These could be hint for the actual onomatopoeia to identify : it starts with a 'C', then a kind of 'R', then maybe a 'D' ?

Yet I hate a silent breath, and a whisper is my death.

> Like above, it ends with a whispered sound, like a 'F' or a 'S'

I need your help to find out what is the actual answer ;)